# How to reference a JButton via combined variable values?

Tags: java

I have some buttons on named `btnA1`, `btnA2`, `btnA3`, `btnB1`, `btnB2`, `btnB3`, and so forth. I want to know how I can reference to them by combining variable values. For example:

```
String var1 = "A";
int var2 = 2;
btn[var1+var2].setText("foo"); // <- This line doesn't work. What do I use in place of this one?
```

Supposedly, the above code will reference to `btnA2` but it doesn't work.

Comment: In Java, there aren't viable options for this. I suppose one could try something nasty with Reflection, but a couple of ifs are much cleaner.

Comment: *"What do I use in place of this one?"*  [Reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/).  But note that reflection is often the right answer to the wrong question.  The *right* question being 'how to design an app. that can offer X feature to user?'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this in Java. But you can store your buttons in an array.

```
JButton [] arr = new JButton[6];
//add buttons in the array
btn[1].setText("foo");
```

Or in a `Map` :

```
Map<String, JButton> m = new HashMap<>();
m.put("A2", btnA2)

m.get(var1+var2).setText("foo");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't  assign button name dynamically.

```
 btn[var1+var2].setText("foo");//This is not possible in java
```

Alternatively design an array of `JButton`

```
JButton[] buts=new JButton[]{btnA1, btnA2, btnA3};

for(JButton but: buts){
  but.setText("foo");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best option for you would be a map:

```
Map<String, JButton> btn = new HashMap<>();
btn.get(var1+var2).setText("foo");
```